# Sum second column elements based on first column elements - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrix with more than 1000 rows, and two columns.
Everytime the first column is '0', the second has a value, and everytime the first column is '1', the second is zero.
Example:

```
M = [0 23;0 35;1 0;1 0;0 2;1 0]

M =

     0    23
     0    35
     1     0
     1     0
     0     2
     1     0
```

Let's think about the second column as a non periodic cycle.

What I want is, everytime the first column is 0 (until is one again), having the opportunity to analyse the size and sum of the second column. In the end I want to know which cycle is bigger in size and sum. (in the example matrix, as output, I know the first cycle is the bigger with a sum of 58).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input two-column array, here's one approach with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
%// Create ID array for using with accumarray
id = cumsum([1;diff(A(:,1))~=0]);

%// Get summations and counts for all IDs
sums = accumarray(id,A(:,2));
counts = accumarray(id,1);

%// Get offset in case the starting element in first column is not 0
offset = (A(1,1)~=0)+1;

%// Consider only even IDs corresponding to 0 elements cycle
sums = sums(offset:2:end)
counts = counts(offset:2:end)
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1    34
     1    45
     0    23
     0    35
     1     0
     1     0
     0     2
     0     8
     0     6
     1     9
sums =
    58
    16
counts =
     2
     3
```

Comment: @Diacula What must be the output for such a `A`?

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. However this code only works if there is two consecutive numbers. In case A =[0 23;0 35;0 2;0 25;1 0;1 0] it won't work. And if almost every "cycles" has different sizes? How can I do that?

Comment: The output is the one you did, the sums and the counts.

Comment: @Diacula I meant if `A =[0 23;0 35;0 2;0 25;1 0;1 0]`, what must be the expected output? So, what must be the expected `sums` and `counts` values for that  `A`?

Comment: in this case only would be one sum=85 and count=1.

Comment: @Diacula I assuumed that `counts` would represent the number of elements in each `0` cycle. That's why when ran on the above listed `A`, we would have `counts` as `4` as there are 4 such consecutive `0's`. Could you state what do you intend to get from the `size` or `counts`?

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake, I need to wait 5min to edit. I mean count=4. I want to count the zeros in the first column. It's what you did, I just can´t make it work for very large matrix. But thanks for all the help

Comment: So, you meant `counts` must be `4`, right? That's what you would get when run the proposed solution on the listed `A` : `A =[0 23;0 35;0 2;0 25;1 0;1 0]`. Make sure your `A` is a two column matrix.